# How to recover the deleted Tasks from a Deleted Profile?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, data-recovery

Edit:  OK.  I've found the OST with the tasks in it, but I am unable to import an OST into outlook, it appears it needs to be converted to PST first.  Is there anyone who knows a free OST -> PST converter or some way to import OSTs directly into outlook?

I am using outlook 2007 linked to an MSN email account through outlook connector.

I recently added 2ndEmail@msn.com (Fake address) to my outlook and deleted 1stEmail@msn.com.  I thought my tasks were locally stored seperately from the email address, but it turns out when I deleted 1stEmail@msn.com, I also lost all of my tasks.  This is catastrophic.

Is there any way to recover them?  They're not stored on the MSN web account.  I figure they must still be somewhere on my computer.  I just don't know where to look or how to look there.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a complete answer, but search for .pst files on your PC.  There are apps for this, but they are not cheap.

Comment: see if this helps http://www.ehow.com/how_4464383_restore-deleted-files-from-microsoft.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this Works , try this ONLY if everything else seems to fail

Here is  the extract from the thread

http://bhandler.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!1pt1v0Q4vD8jSvNS4lqdAuug!391.entry (read comments given here)

> *So we’ll first need to “corrupt” our*
>   *PST file to have ScanPST reclaim our*
>   *“deleted” emails.*
>
> 1)  Locate and backup your Outlook PST file
>
> 2)  From the Command Prompt type what’s in bold (note the hyphens "-")
>
> **`DEBUG C:\fullpath\OutlookFile.PST`**
>
> **`- f  107  113  20`**
>
> **`- q`**
>
> 3)  Now that you’ve “corrupted” your PST file run ScanPST (usually
>   found in C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\System\Mapi\1033)
>
> 4)  Once ScanPST completes, your deleted emails will be restored.

**The below extract from**

http://recovermyfiles.com/recover-deleted-email.php

> PST files are very complex and in some
>   instances recovered PST files will not
>   function until they have also been
>   repaired. This is done by running a
>   program called 'scanpst.exe' (also
>   known as the 'Inbox Repair Tool')
>   which is installed by default on all
>   Windows computer systems. If errors
>   occur when you try to access it, use
>   the Inbox Repair Tool to fix it. Once
>   you have recovered and repaired the
>   file you will once again be able to
>   open the file in Microsoft Outlook.

Comment: Please give source credit for the last paragraph.  I know it's on this product website, as well as other locations: http://www.recovermyfiles.com/recover-deleted-email.php

Comment: @JNK oops I must have forgot, thanks for reminding me . I haven't sleep for past 3 days so I am forgetting things quickly